# I can't unplug my Laptop!

Tags: power-management, battery

Since I started using Ubuntu last week my battery is running out so fast!

When I used to use Windows 10 the battery won't run out of charge that fast even when I am playing games. (By the way my laptop is brand new so the problem isn't the battery itself)

I even downloaded an extension that controls the CPU frequency and I set it to the half but that doesn't help!!

I have plugged my laptop two hours ago and it still didn't hit the 90%, I am using it while it is charging though.

Comment: I would possibly check your motherboard firmware/BIOS settings to see if there's something you can do.  I suggest monitoring your system resources with something like `htop`.  This could clue you in if there is some errant process that is using your hardware excessively: that could contribute to battery running down fast.  Other than that, I would caution you to rule out a hardware/battery issue just because it's new.  Hardware failure happens on a "bathtub curve"; it's actually more common for hardware to fail when it's new, than it does at the end of the advertised lifespan

Comment: I ruled out the battery issue because I still have the windows on my other hdd and when I play games on windows, the battery usage is normal!!